# Is it possible to get US J1 visa (trainee program) as software developer? (I don't have a degree)

Tags: usa, visa, working

I don't have a degree, but I have 4 years (2010-2014) of experience in software development and 4 years (2006-2010) as lead technical support engineer.

I see the following requirements for J1 trainee at:

http://j1visa.state.gov/programs/trainee/

> Has a degree or professional certificate from a foreign post-secondary
>   academic institution and at least one year of prior related work
>   experience in his or her occupational field outside the United States;
>   **or**
>
> **Has five years of work experience** outside the United States in the occupational field in which they are seeking training.

Can I get J1 visa (trainee) as software developer in Intel or HP (because they are in list)? (of course if these companies accept me)

Comment: Accept you as what? J1 is for **internships**.

Comment: I'm trying to find legal basis for getting a temporary job in USA (it would be good for my CV, then I can relocate to EU easily [to Intel EU branch]). J1 **is not** only for **internships**. **Internship** is just one of several J1 programs. But I'm not qualified under J1 **internship**. Although I found that there is J1 **trainee** where I **would be qualified**. There are a few companies who provide J1 **trainee** (see the link). One of them is **Intel**. That's why I posted this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking about work. I'll quote from your comment:

> "I'm trying to find legal basis for getting a temporary job in USA"

J1 is **not** a work visa. J1 is issued for internships and trainings. If you're coming to work - you cannot do it on J1.

In any case, this is something that the company has to deal with. If they "accept" you, as you say, they'll refer your case to their immigration lawyer, together with the program/job details, and the lawyer will decide whether *you* qualify for a status based on the contract offered to *you*.

Comment: I see. I thought that J1 is only chance. But in this case, I think I have no options at all. AFAIK, only H1-B visa is available for software developers. But I'm not qualified for H1-B (neither degree, nor 12 years of experience).

Comment: @uintptr_t You got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can 'work' with the J1 Trainee or Intern visa. An internship or Trainee Program means to work with a small wage and expand your knowledge in those months spent in the US. It's just that the programs are not intended for making money, but to help you expand your knowledge in your related field and as a cultural exchange as well, which would benefit both your country and US citizens that you interact with.

Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a source / reference for this?